# How could I get a count of unread feed elements?

Tags: chatter-feed

I’m trying to get the number of unread feed-elements for a given user, using Chatter API, but I don’t know if there is an easier way to do that.

Last API release includes some information about whether a feed element has beed readByMe or not, so that could give us the number. The downside of it would be to get all feed-elements, which are paginated, and iterate them to read readBy property.

I know there is an endpoint to get a count of unread conversation `/connect/communities/communityId/chatter/users/userId/conversations/unread-count` but I’m not sure if it is what I want, I don’t know the differences between a feed-element and a conversation. Also, if I try to use this endpoint I get an error:

> "You do not have permission to use Chatter Messages. Your organization may >not have permission or may not have enabled Chatter Messages.  If you're >in a network, Chatter Messages may not be enabled for the network."

I’ve also tried using `/chatter/feeds/record/recordId/feed-elements`, however, it's not valid either, because it is for feed groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unread conversation endpoint you posted is for private conversations and is very different from a feed.

While there is a readBy capability for a feed element to show whether the context user has read it or not, there is currently no easy way to get the total number of unread feed-elements for a feed, such as a news feed for a user.

Your approach to get all the feed-elements and total up the unread count would work, but it will be very process intensive, especially for a very large feed. It will lightly run up your api call limit very quickly and I would not recommend doing it.

Comment: More or less what we were afraid of. Would you know if we could get that information directly from the database using SOQL? Thank you for answering!

Comment: Unfortunately, no. There is not a field in SOQL to simply retrieve the number of unread posts on a feed for a given user from the database.